# SABR Model Implied Volatility in VBA

Tags: vba, quantitative-finance

I am trying to write a code that is going to calculate the implied volatility according to the SABR Model given the the mentioned parameters. However, I always get NA for ATM vol. Implied volatility formula being used is this one: [image]

```
Function SABRIV(alpha As Double, beta As Double, v As Double, rho As Double, f As Double, k As Double, T As Double) As Double
Dim z As Double
Dim x As Double
Dim numerator As Double
Dim denominator As Double

z = (v / alpha) * ((f * k) ^ ((1 - beta) / 2)) * Application.Ln(f / k)
x = Application.Ln((Sqr(1 - 2 * rho * z + z ^ 2) + z - rho) / (1 - rho))
numerator = ((1 - beta) ^ 2 / 24) * ((alpha ^ 2) / ((f * k) ^ (1 - beta))) + 1 / 4 * (rho * beta * v * alpha) / ((f * k) ^ ((1 - beta) / 2)) + (((2 - 3 * rho ^ 2) * v ^ 2) / 24)
denominator = (((f * k) ^ ((1 - beta) / 2)) * (1 + (((1 - beta) ^ 2) / 24) * (Application.Ln(f / k) ^ 2) + (((1 - beta) ^ 4) / 1920) * (Application.Ln(f / k) ^ 4)))

SABRIV = (alpha * (1 + numerator) * T) / denominator * z / x
End Function
```

Comment: `Ln` and `Sqrt` are not VBA functions - you can use `Application.Ln` and `Sqr`. But aren't you also missing an additional parameter - `T`?

Comment: this is hard to check and modify, break your formula into smaller pieces and calculate them separately and then put them together, there is no need to put everything in one line

Comment: Hi - that answer worked. However, I made some changes to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Volatility `ATM(when f==K)` has a special case formula. Looking at your function, `z/x(z)==1`, the denominator reduces to `f**(1 - beta)` since `log(f/K)` vanishes so you get:

```
SABRIV = (alpha * (1 + numerator) * T) / denominator
```